# How to set Spinner value based on value from database?

Tags: android, spinner

I have been looking for an answer to this question and it took me quite some time, but none of the answers I found here was satisfactory.
The problem is that I wanted to update a record in a database and I needed to transform the database value to a Spinner value. Most of the answers  here mentioned solutions for Spinners based on Arrays, but not on CursorAdapters.

Comment: What problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: No problem anymore. It was a problem for which I could not find a solution here but after a long time I found the above solution and I decided to share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting I have found a solution, which I want to share.

It seems that a Spinner that is based on a CursorAdapter uses a CursorWrapper to get direct access to the Cursor. So, to get access in your code simply use the CursorWrapper.

Below is an extract of the code in one of my programs.

```
TextView mTextView2 = (TextView) v
    .findViewById(R.id.payer_payee_default_category);
Spinner mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.categories_spinner);
CursorWrapper mCursorWrapper;
for (int nbr = 0; nbr < mSpinner.getCount(); nbr++) {
    mCursorWrapper = (CursorWrapper) mSpinner.getItemAtPosition(nbr);
    if (String.valueOf(mCursorWrapper.getString(1)).equals(
            String.valueOf(mTextView2.getText()))) {
        mSpinner.setSelection(nbr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now accept the answer, so that it will be removed from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Comment: I see. I forgot about all those limitations. ;)